# Wait for QGLWidget to finish rendering

Tags: qt, opengl, benchmarking, wait

I'm developing an OpenGL benchmark for a Qt application using VBOs and not glBegin/glEnd stuff.

I call the the class GLWidget (that inherits from public QGLWidget and protected QGLFunctions) from the MainWindow and I want to wait for the rendering to finish and get the value of the variable that stores the time elapsed. Problem is I don't find a suitable SIGNAL / method of waiting for the finish of a QGLWidget, so I get wrong variable values from MainWindow even if I use glFinish() at the end of the rendering.

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
  // VBO, glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData stuff
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    QGLFunctions::glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    QGLFunctions::glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    QGLFunctions::glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

    // Start Time
    startTime = clock();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices); 
    // Wait for the rendering
    glFinish();
    // Finish Time
    finishTime = clock();
    relativeTime = finishTime - startTime;
    totalTime = (float) relativeTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    QGLFunctions::glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own two signals 
        `void startPaint()` and `void endPaint()`
Than catch them somwhere(MainWindow maybe) and `void startPaint()` will start timer, and `void endPaint()` will stop timer and store value somewhere. Qt class `QElapsedTimer` should do the job.